# problem with removing sessions in PHP by unset_session in FireFox

Tags: php, firefox, session, exit, logout

While I'm pressing on log out link it's not exit the user from the page but when I'm refreshing manually after the clicking it really will log out.
The log out command is:

```
$URL = $_GET['url'];
session_unset();
redirect($URL);
```

When the page is redirected I see the session variables although they were deleted and 
just after manual refresh it's OK.

There is no any problem in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't simply a caching issue?  Since clicking refresh shows as logged out, I suspect that this is the issue.

Comment: Do you call session_start() before calling session_unset?

Comment: Brad- so what can I do regarding it? Gerben - Yes, there is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to really log the user out, you need to also unset the session ID and the cookie which is used to propagate the session id to the client.

Here is a sample code from the PHP manual which does that:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Ofir, thanks for you detailed answer but it didn't help. It's still the same. Moreover, it's happening also in log in situation in FireFox.